# Should I use composite key or primary key from other table

Tags: mysql, database-design, query-performance, primary-key, index-design

We have a Education Project which has following entities :

- Domain (e.g. Programming, UI/UX, AI, ML), each Domain has 5 Levels (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
- Building Blocks - which are like small topics e.g. java, multi-threading, loops, prototyping, user interviews. Each Level in the Domain is build of multiple Building Blocks.
- Learning Asset (is like a link to study a concept - it can be associated with multiple Building Blocks) and further these Learning Assets are mapped to a particular Domain -> Level -> Building Block

These are the tables that we have thought of :

`Domain`

```
|    id     |      Name          |     
|    10     |      UIUX          |    
|    11     |      Programming   |    
|    12     |      AI            |
```

`Building Blocks`

```
|    id    |      Name               |     
|    1     |       loops             |    
|    2     |     multi-threading     |    
|    3     |     user-interview      |
```

Then we store mapping of Building Blocks to a Domain - Level

`Domain-Level-BuildingBlocks` Mapping Table

```
|  DLB_Id    |       domainId   |   level      |   buildingBlockId 
|    100     |        11        |    1         |    1
|    200     |        11        |    2         |    2
|    300     |        10        |    1         |    3
```

in this table - `(domainId, level, buildingBlockId)` form a composite key

`Learning Asset` Table

```
|    id    |       Name                 |   link     
|    1     |      Loop Notes            |    https://a.com       
|    2     |       Operators            |    https://b.com       
|    3     |       Process and Threads  |    https://c.com
```

A Learning Asset can be connected to multiple building blocks

`Learning Asset -BuildingBlocks` Mapping Table

```
|    id    |       learningAssetId  |     buildingBlockId 
|    1     |        1               |        1
|    2     |        2               |        1
|    3     |        3               |        2
```

Now the Admin can select if a Learning Asset is applicable in Domain-Level-BuildingBlock combination so

`Learning Asset-Domain-Level-BuildingBlocks` Mapping Table **(Table A)**

```
|    id    |       learningAssetId  |   domainId   |   level      |   buildingBlockId 
|    1     |        1               |      11      |    1         |      1
|    2     |        2               |      11      |    1         |      1
```

in this table - `(domainId, level, buildingBlockId)` form a composite key

My question was in the above table :  should I again store **(domainId, level, buildingBlockId)** or should I use their primary key **DLB_id** from the **`Domain-Level-BuildingBlocks` table**

something like this :

`Learning Asset-Domain-Level-BuildingBlocks` Mapping Table **(Table B)**

```
|    id    |       learningAssetId  |   DLB_Id   
|    1     |        1               |      100   
|    2     |        3               |      200
```

1. My question is whether to use Table A or Table B
2. If Table B is the correct way should I generate DLB_Id as string by combining `domainId + "-" + level + "-" + buildingBlockId` instead of using Auto-increment Integet Primary Keys. Will the indexing on the generated string be as efficient as the Auto-increment Integer Primary Key.  The reason for generating the string is that when we need to fetch the Learning Assets that belong to a Domain-Level-BuildingBlock combination I don't need to use the `Domain-Level-BuildingBlocks` Mapping Table - rather I can directly look up the generated string Id in the `Learning Asset-Domain-Level-BuildingBlocks` Mapping Table

`Learning Asset-Domain-Level-BuildingBlocks` Mapping Table **(Table C)**

```
|    id    |       learningAssetId  |         DLB_Id   (as generated string)
|    1     |        1               |        '11-1-1'
|    2     |        3               |        '11-2-2'
```

i.e. Table B or Table C ?

Thank you

Comment: Two questions 1. Can a `BuildingBlock` occur at more than one level? 2. Are learning assets always URLs or are there other items you are linking to?  General comments: 1. You should *always* use composite primary keys unless the key itself becomes too wide (in bytes, not columns) 2. When starting a data modeling exercise, don't add surrogates until the very end - data mock-ups are fine, but replacing things with numbers obfuscates things unnecessarily.

Comment: 1. Yes BuildingBlock can occur in Different Domains at different levels. 
2. Learning Assets will be URL only

What are surrogates ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, a mapping table does not need its own id.  Instead, the `PRIMARY KEY` should be a composite key with the 2 (or more) column-ids referencing the tables that are being related in a many-to-many relationship.

For a 1-to-many relationship, a mapping table is unnecessary.

Your "DLB" smells like a "Relation", hence the above comments apply.  If, instead, you can reasonably think of it as an "Entity", then it would have its own id.  And it would probably have more columns of attributes of the "entity".

Comment: Thank you Rick. So if the mapping table has some additional fields like deleted_At, deleted_By it is still ok to just use the composite keys right?

Comment: Yes, it is OK to have other columns like that.  See also http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table .  The composite PK is for performance; `deleted` would not be included in the PK.

Comment: In DLB table we have a composite key on (domainId, level, buildingBlockId) but most of our look up is going to be to find building blocks at a different levels of a domain - so shall we define index on (domainId, level) as well

Comment: @j10 - No. If you have `INDEX(a,b,c)`, you do not also need `INDEX(a,b)`.  That is, if an index matches exactly the left part of another index, it is unnecessary.